# Запрос в базу MySQL не добавляет данные.

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база MySQL в ней есть поля id, login, password, email. При попытке добавить туда данные запрос проходит успешно, но в базу ничего не заносится. Я сам что-то не смог разобраться в чем причина. В чем ошибка ? И еще если не сложно то как бы выглядел запрос с mysqli? В чем там различие, я когда пытался его использовать постоянно были ошибки.

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password1'];
$email = $_POST["email"];

include_once '../dbcon.php';

//Проверка есть ли такой логин
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='".$login."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (!empty($row['id'])) {
    exit("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин.");
}

if(empty($login) || empty($email) || empty($password) || (strlen($login) < 5) ) {
    exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
}
else {(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login,password,mail) VALUES ('" . $login . "','" . $password . "','" . $email . "')")); 
echo 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!';}
```

Comment: а какая имеено ошибка вылазит?

Comment: Ошибок никаких не выводится. Пишет только 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!' .

Comment: в таблице бд вообще никаких изменений или добавляется строка с пустыми полями?

Comment: Таблица совершенно пустая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот это

```
else {(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login,password,mail) VALUES ('" . $login . "','" . $password . "','" . $email . "')")); 
echo 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!';}
```

замени на

```
else {
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login,password,mail) VALUES ('" . $login . "','" . $password . "','" . $email . "')")or die("Ошибки запроса: " . mysql_error());
echo 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!';
}
```

выполни и посмотри че выдаст

Comment: Если убрать лишнюю скобку то все работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в код  "or die (mysql_error())" вот так:

```
else {(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(login,password,mail) VALUES ('" .$login . "','" . $password . "','" .$email . "')") or die(mysql_error()));  echo 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!';}
```

И если честно, я не понимаю, зачем нужны скобки вокруг оператора mysql_query